# How to clear errors in xmpp chat program in android

Tags: android

Hi I am creating a chat application using xmpp. My problem is that while running the project  a dialog box appears showing 'your project contain errors fix then and run', but there is no errors shown in project explorer, a warning is sign is shown(hope it doesn't effect rnuning a project). The console page is showing like this :

```
[2013-09-25 10:25:01 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/kenai/jbosh/AbstractAttr;
[2013-09-25 10:25:01 - XMPPChatDemo] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/kenai/jbosh/AbstractAttr;
```

And my program code is :

```
public class XMPPChatDemoActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String HOST = "192.168.1.4";
    public static final int PORT = 5222;
    public static final String USERNAME = "semyma";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "computer";
    private XMPPConnection connection;
    private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private EditText recipient;
    private EditText textMessage;
    private ListView listview;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        recipient = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.toET);
        textMessage = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.chatET);
        listview = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
        setListAdapter();
        // Set a listener to send a chat text message
        Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String to = recipient.getText().toString();
                String text = textMessage.getText().toString();
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Sending text " + text + " to " + to);
                Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
                msg.setBody(text);              
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.sendPacket(msg);
                    messages.add(connection.getUser() + ":");
                    messages.add(text);
                    setListAdapter();
                }
            }
        });

        connect();
    }

    /**
     * Called by Settings dialog when a connection is establised with the XMPP
     * server
     * 
     * @param connection
     */
    public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        if (connection != null) {
            // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
            PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
            connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                @Override
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    Message message = (Message) packet;
                    if (message.getBody() != null) {
                        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                                .getFrom());
                        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Text Recieved " + message.getBody()
                                + " from " + fromName );
                        messages.add(fromName + ":");
                        messages.add(message.getBody());
                        // Add the incoming message to the list view
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                setListAdapter();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, filter);
        }
    }

    private void setListAdapter() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.listitem, messages);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public void connect() {

        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
                "Connecting...", "Please wait...", false);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Create a connection
                ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                        HOST, PORT);
                XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
                try {
                    connection.connect();
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Connected to " + connection.getHost());
                } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to connect to "
                            + connection.getHost());
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                    setConnection(null);
                }
                try {
                    // SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
                    connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());
                    // Set the status to available
                    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                    connection.sendPacket(presence);
                    setConnection(connection);
                    Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "--------------------------------------");
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "User: " + entry.getUser());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "Name: " + entry.getName());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "Type: " + entry.getType());
                        Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry
                                .getUser());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "
                                + entryPresence.getStatus());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: "
                                + entryPresence.getType());
                        Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                        if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : "
                                + entryPresence);

                    }
                } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "
                            + USERNAME);
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                    setConnection(null);
                }

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: try cleaning the project

Comment: Delete "bin" folder and clean buuld

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this happens due to the multiple copies of ***android-support-v4*** libraries in your project and and dependent project.

First try to delete the other ***android-support-v4*** library and make it same for all.
if this works for you then its good other wise follow the below steps thats gonna work with you

1- List item

2-Open Project Build Path,

3-Select "Libraries" tab,

4-Remove all library except the Android Library

5-Adding all required JARs Files

And you are Done.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs you will better understand by this example - In case you download any project in this project environment means SDK updated in API LEVEL 15 and such type of project you import in your work-space and at this time point to be noted your SDK updated in API LEVEL
19 at this time fixed project setup and it will goes Build Path at this you just add external
libraries android-support-v4 then this problem has occurs due to the multiple copies of android-support-v4/google-play-services if you use Google map  libraries in your project.

i hope so you will better understand.

Thankys