# Library not working both together asmack-android-19-0.8.10 and quickblox-android-1.2.4.jar in android

Tags: android, xmpp, quickblox, asmack

I will working on xmpp chat application with quickblox video calling. This two jar file add on libs folder then i will run the apps and console throw two error like as

**One** is [Dex Loader]
 **Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/kenai/jbosh/AbstractAttr;**

**Second** is [SampleApp] **Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/kenai/jbosh/AbstractAttr;**

Not working both together jar file on private library.

So guys please help and share your knowledge and thanks in Advance.

Comment: This question might have been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996776/how-to-clear-errors-in-xmpp-chat-program-in-android

Comment: Thanks for reply, But That question about solution on error regarding of xmpp not a library issues.

Comment: If you have any idea about this question then say me or post answer.